# c - comparing argv to string literals more elegantly

Tags: c, loops, if-statement, stdin, argv

my code looks like this:

```
if((strcmp(argv[1], "-a") == 0) && (argc == 3)) {
    /* my code */
} else if((strcmp(argv[1], "-b") == 0) && (argc == 3)) {
    /* my code */
} ...
```

And so on. Is this the only way to work around comparing args? I read someplace that it can be done using a loop, but I can't seem to figure out how. Right now, my code is kind of saturated with these if statements.

Thank you, this is my first question, I won't be asking one again, I like to figure things out on my own. But right now, time is of the essence.

So, is there a crispier way to do this?

Comment: Take a look at [getopt](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Getopt.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a C function for that: [getopt()](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Example-of-Getopt.html#Example-of-Getopt)

Comment: Shouldn't to say "GNU'S C function"?